# Extending Linux LVM partition

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, lvm

I was following this [link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006371) to extend a Linux LVM partition on a remote machine, but the Internet connection went out and I don't know if the partition was created.

Can you help me determine if the new partition was created successfully?.

On this machine I only have one disk that initially was 20Gb, now it's 53,7GB.

The server is an an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Here's my fdisk -l

```
Disco /dev/sda: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes  
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 6527 cilindros, 104857600 sectores en total  
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Identificador del disco: 0x000eeac0  
Dispositivo Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema  
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux  
/dev/sda2          501758    41940991    20719617    5  Extendida  
/dev/sda3          499712      501757        1023   8e  Linux LVM  
/dev/sda5          501760    41940991    20719616   8e  Linux LVM  
Las entradas de la tabla de particiones no están en el orden del disco  
Disco /dev/mapper/RIS-root: 19.1 GB, 19050528768 bytes  
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 2316 cilindros, 37208064 sectores en total  
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Identificador del disco: 0x00000000  
El disco /dev/mapper/RIS-root no contiene una tabla de particiones válida  
Disco /dev/mapper/RIS-swap_1: 2143 MB, 2143289344 bytes  
255 cabezas, 63 sectores/pista, 260 cilindros, 4186112 sectores en total  
Unidades = sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Tamaño de sector (lógico / físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Tamaño E/S (mínimo/óptimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Identificador del disco: 0x00000000  
El disco /dev/mapper/RIS-swap_1 no contiene una tabla de particiones válida
```

I created the partition n° 3 with all the free space (53.7-20=~30Gb), but it looks like it's very small, can you tell its size in MB?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The size of the partition /dev/sda3 is around 1 MB.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the partition from my volume group using vgreduce RIS /dev/sda3.

Comment: Now I have to delete that partition. I've tried to mount it to see if it contains any data using mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/disk3 but it says "must specify filesystem type", looks like it's not even formatted. Can I safely delete the partition?.

Comment: If you created the partition recently without assigning a filesystem type (ext3, ext4, etc) it is not going to contain any data and you should be free to delete the partition. Also you cannot mount it without assigning a filesystem before.